# Headphone jack not working

Tags: 12.04

I have hp dv6-6119TX in which I have 2 operating systems -UBUNTU 12.04(and it is completely updated) & Win 7 Ultimate.
The earphone jack works properly in windows but it is not working in UBUNTU.Kindly help me out.